# Используя Appodeal получаю ошибку duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, архитектура, framework

Всем привет. Перетащил Framework Appodeal в корень проекта. После загрузки проекта получаю ошибку duplicate symbols for architecture arm64! Если зайти в Build Phases -> Link Binary и удалить от туда Appodeal.framework, проект собирается без ошибок. Но когда начинаю использовать библиотеку Appodeal, проект собирается с ошибкой symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7!

Answer (score 1):

Вернул Appodeal.framework обратно в Build Phases -> Link Binary и удалил флаг -all_load из Other Linker Flags. Теперь проект собирается без ошибок.